# Stripe Embeddable Pricing Table - Set Billing Cycle Anchor

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there any way to set the [billing cycle anchor](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle) when using Stripe's [embeddable pricing table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table)? We really like the convenience and design of the pricing table for our product, but we need to anchor our subscriptions to the first of each month. This functionality is available when using the API or Checkout, but we're not sure how to do it via the pricing table (or if it's even possible).

We're not opposed to workarounds if it lets us keep using the pricing table and not have to build our own... The benefits of having an attractive, drop-in pricing table UI we can simply control from the Stripe dashboard are great. Really hoping to figure out a way to anchor subscriptions...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe does not offer this feature today with PricingTable. It would be a feature request that you would direct to their support team [here](https://support.stripe.com/contact)